# Javascript for making the element disappear and reappear after scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want an element to disappear and reappear after scrolling from the top. I found javascript for this, but something is not right. I don't know much about JS, I found it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp), inserted it, but it doesn't work as it should - it only makes element to change position. Multiple examples of javascript I found on StackExchange and on the Internet don't work either for some reason.

How do I make the element disappear after scrolling down and reappear after scrolling back to the top?

I also have set CSS for this element on smaller screens, should I make a separate script for smaller screens then?

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("stub").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("stub").style.top = "150px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
.stub {
  background-color: #577284;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

#stublink {
  color: #F3E0BE;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stub:hover .pagenav {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.pagenav {
  background-color: #577284;
  display: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  border-top: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.pagenav a {
  display: block;
  color: #F3E0BE;
  padding: 6px 0px 0px 8px;
}

.pagenav a:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 0 #ff8000
}

body {
  height: 200vh
}

;
@media only screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  .stub {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
  }
  .stub:hover .pagenav {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="stub" id="stub">
    <div class="pagenav">
      <a href="#last">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>02.19 03.20</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#previous">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>02.18 02.19</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#dec17">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>12.17 04.18</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#nov17">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>11.17 01.18</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#sep16">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>09.16 11.17</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#sep15">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>09.15 08.16</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#jan15">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>01.15 03.16</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#jan14">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>01.14 08.15</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div><a id="stublink" href=#>Pagemenu</a>
  </div>
  <script></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change that line document.getElementById("stub").style.top = "0"; for that document.getElementById("stub").style.block = "block";

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("stub").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("stub").style.display = "none";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
.stub {
  background-color: #577284;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

#stublink {
  color: #F3E0BE;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stub:hover .pagenav {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.pagenav {
  background-color: #577284;
  display: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  border-top: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.pagenav a {
  display: block;
  color: #F3E0BE;
  padding: 6px 0px 0px 8px;
}

.pagenav a:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 0 #ff8000
}

body {
  height: 200vh
}

;
@media only screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  .stub {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
  }
  .stub:hover .pagenav {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="stub" id="stub">
    <div class="pagenav">
      <a href="#last">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>02.19 03.20</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#previous">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>02.18 02.19</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#dec17">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>12.17 04.18</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#nov17">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>11.17 01.18</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#sep16">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>09.16 11.17</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#sep15">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>09.15 08.16</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#jan15">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>01.15 03.16</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#jan14">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>01.14 08.15</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div><a id="stublink" href=#>Pagemenu</a>
  </div>
  <script></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to play with the [`style.display`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp) property of the element with `id` "stub" and set it to:

- "block" when `prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos`;
- "none" in the other cases.

```js
var prevScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  document.getElementById("stub").style.display = prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos ? "block" : "none";
  prevScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
.stub {
  background-color: #577284;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

#stublink {
  color: #F3E0BE;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stub:hover .pagenav {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.pagenav {
  background-color: #577284;
  display: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  border-top: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.pagenav a {
  display: block;
  color: #F3E0BE;
  padding: 6px 0px 0px 8px;
}

.pagenav a:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 0 #ff8000
}

body {
  height: 200vh
}

;
@media only screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  .stub {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
  }
  .stub:hover .pagenav {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="stub" id="stub">
  <div class="pagenav">
    <a href="#last">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>02.19 03.20</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#previous">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>02.18 02.19</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#dec17">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>12.17 04.18</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#nov17">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>11.17 01.18</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#sep16">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>09.16 11.17</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#sep15">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>09.15 08.16</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#jan15">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>01.15 03.16</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#jan14">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>01.14 08.15</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
  </div><a id="stublink" href=#>Pagemenu</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the **intersection observer** api
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Be careful if you want to use the `display` css property because with display property:

- if an element is `display: none` it will not be rendered at all (try with `visibility: hidden` or with `opacity: 0`)
- css transition do not work.

So I would suggest to use opacity.

---

css

```
.stub {
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}
.stub.triggered {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

---

javascript:

```
const options = {
    root: null, // The document viewport (default)
    rootMargin: '0px', // No offset from the root element (default)
    threshold: 1.0, // Full intersection into the root element
};

const obs = new IntersectionObserver( elms => {
    elms.forEach( curr => {
        if(curr.intersectionRatio < options.threshold) {
            curr.target.classList.remove('triggered')
        } else {
            curr.target.classList.add('triggered')
        }
    })

}, options)

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.stub')).forEach(obs.observe.bind(obs))
```

As you can see on the MDN page, there is a Internet Explorer polyfill if needed https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver